# Why is the 2.2k resistor needed in an MT3608 module?

Tags: resistors, boost

I am trying to implement an MT3608 module on my PCB. I went through its schematic which clearly describes the module.

I see they have used 2.2k ohm resistor in addition to a potentiometer. From what I read in datasheet of [MT3608](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/1131968/ETC1/MT3608.html) is that it needs 0.6V on the FB pin. There voltage divider for that. I don't understand why there is an extra 2.2k resistor used in the module. Is it for safety? Does anyone know the reason for that resistor?

Also I am planning to use a fixed value resistor (no potentiometer) as my output voltage is fixed to 12V.
Do I have to consider this extra resistor ?

Does nyone know a locally available resistor combination that gives R1/R2 ratio 19? I need it for 12V output.

[image: Schematic of mt3608 module]

Comment: Try to think about what will happen if you turn R2 all the way down so that the FB pin of the MT3608 is directly connected to R1. What will be the voltage across R1? Now remove R1, then the FB pin would be connected directly to ground. Think about how this relates to having 0.6 V on the FB pin. Can there then be 0.6 V on the FB pin? What will happen to the voltage at the output (OUT+)? Hint: the MT3608 works such that it increases the output voltage until there's 0.6 V at the FB pin.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Yes. got it. Thank You for explanation. So if I put fixed value resistor there wont be any problem as there will always be some resistance.

Comment: *So if I put fixed value resistor there wont be any problem as there will always be some resistance* You cannot just **any** resistor value, the ratio R2/R1 sets the maximum output voltage which should not become too high (reverse voltage of D1 and the maximum voltage rating of C2).

Comment: Yes I will calculate value of resistor accordingly. After that there should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2k2 resistor is there to provide a minimum value of what is adjustable with R2.

R2 is a trimpot.

If you adjust R2 to the minimum, it will be at least 2k2ohm, which is perhaps a requirement of the chip. It cannot regulate if the feedback is tied to the ground.

Answer (score 0):

The 2k2 resistor is to limit the output voltage to around 28V.
As per datasheet:

[image]

If you need to get the output voltage Vo the ratio is R1/(R1+R2)  for 0.6/Vo so for 12V R2/R1=19 not R1/R2.

Comment: Yes you are right, Even if you see the other way, the equation is Vo = Vref x (1+(R1/R2)).
Both are same. For 12v volt, R1/R2 should be 19. I just tried to put it directly.